# Permission issues in GCP Container Registry

Tags: docker, cluster, google-kubernetes-engine

We need some help.
We don't see any docker registry in GCP. It says that it has permission issues but we have enough permissions to do everything in there. Also we cannot connect  any cluster in GKE.
Could it be some technical problems on it that can comes from billing?

*Note: We added all permission such as "OWNER" of the project.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no detailed error log so please have a look at the Container Registry documentation you could learn about [Troubleshooting permissions](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/troubleshooting#permission_issues).

Due I don’t have any more information about how you want to connect clusters in GKE check the [Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting) guide on GKE.  Please tell me specifically the error log.

I suspect there are no technical problems related to billing in your case,  otherwise you will get notifications telling you that.